# When to take log in integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

When is log taken in integrals and when its not and why? 
which of the below is correct and why?

$$\int {1\over\sqrt{t}} dt = \log |\sqrt{t}| + C$$

or

$$\int {1\over\sqrt{t}}dt = 2\sqrt{t} + C$$

Comment: What are you integrating with respect to?

Comment: Compute derivative of the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,
$$\int \frac{dt}{t}=\ln|t|+c$$

You don't 'take logs' when you're integrating per se, rather you use techniques like substitution, or algebraic manipulation, trig rules etc, to change an integral *you don't know* into an integral *you do know*.

Here's an example of algebraic manipulation:

$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=\int \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}=\int t^{-1/2}\,dt=\frac{t^{1/2}}{1/2}+c=2t^{1/2}+c$$

Here we used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to know $$\int t^n \,dt=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}+c\quad \text{for } n\neq -1 $$

On the other hand suppose you want to find

$$\int \tan(t) \,dt=\int \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}\,dt$$

If you don't know offhand, then you might try a substitution $u=\cos(t)$, $du=-\sin(t) dt$. Thus

$$\int \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}\,dt=-\int \frac{du}{u} $$

Now it's in the form we know for the logarithm so

$$\int \tan(t) \,dt=\int \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}\,dt =-\int \frac{du}{u}=-\ln|u|+c=-\ln|\cos(t)|+c$$

We can check if we're right,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\ln|f(t)|=\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$$

So,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(-\ln|\cos(t)|\right)=-\frac{-\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}=\tan(t)$$

To summarise, in general

$$\int \frac{dt}{f(t)}\color{red}{\neq} \ln|f(t)|+c$$

For some examples to back this up there's a nice table at [Pauls online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/CommonErrors/CalculusErrors.aspx)

[image]